# Dynamically extend `__del__` cleanup code on an instance

Tags: python, namedtuple, del, dynamic-class-creation

I want to bind a dynamically created `namedtuple` to a class

1. When an instance of the class is initialized, a new `namedtuple`-type is created, and registered in `globals()` (this allows pickling).
2. When the instance is deleted, I want to perform cleanup of the registration in `globals()`.

I already have working code for this:

```py
from collections import namedtuple

class ClassWithTuple:
    tuple_id: str
    tuple_type: type[tuple]

    def __init__(self, name: str, fields: list[str]) -> None:
        self.tuple_type = namedtuple(name, fields)
        self.tuple_id = f"_{name}_{self.__class__.__name__}_{hash(self)}"
        self.tuple_type.__qualname__ = self.tuple_id

        if self.tuple_id in globals():
            raise RuntimeError(f"A class '{self.tuple_id}' exists!")
        globals()[self.tuple_id] = self.tuple_id

    def __del__(self):
        del globals()[self.tuple_id]
        del self

obj = ClassWithTuple("FooTuple", ["a", "b", "c"])
obj.tuple_type(1, 2, 3)
```

What I'd like to do is refactor this in the form

```py
class ClassWithTuple
    tuple_id: str
    tuple_type: type[tuple]

    def __init__(self, name: str, fields: list[str]) -> None:
        register_tuple(self, name, fields)
```

or possibly `self.tuple_id, self.tuple_type = register_tuple(self, name, fields)`.

How can I automagically add the required `__del__` cleanup code? (Especially, if the class defined `__del__`, then `del globals()[self.tuple_id]` should be *prepended* I suppose.)

Comment: `__del__` should rarely (if ever) be used for cleanup; use a context manager instead.

Comment: @chepner Can you expand on that? Where would I put the context manager? Again the behaviour I want is that if the instance is deleted, the attached tuple class is deleted as well, and all the responsible code should ideally be hidden in the `register_tuple` call.